# Randomly selecting subquestions in exsheets

Tags: exsheets

Here in the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{exsheets}
\SetupExSheets{counter-format=}
\begin{document}
\begin{question}[name=Answer the following in one sentence]
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item Who is the President?
    \item Who is the Prime minister?
    \item \includequestions[random=2]{classA}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{question}
\end{document}
```

The contents of classA.tex are:

```
\begin{input}
  \begin{question}
    Who is the Defence Minister?
  \end{question}
  \begin{question}
    Who is the Home Minister?
  \end{question}
  \begin{question}
    Who is the Finance Minister?
  \end{question}
  \begin{question}
    Who is the External Affairs Minister?
  \end{question}
\end{input}
```

Here is how it looks when compiled:

[image: Compiled Image]

The problem is around Item No. 3. The question text is repeated and the counter does not advance.

How do I overcome this? So, it will select questions randomly and will assign item nos. 3 and 4 to them?

If exsheets can not do this, is there another package that can do this?

Comment: `exsheets` does not allow you to select random subquestions. You get exactly what is expected: nested `question` environments… it *might* be possible (with some fantasy) with `xsim` but I have to experiment first

Comment: I might have something but I don't have much time left... I will post a solution with `xsim` this weekend…

Comment: @clemens anything that will show me a way out? If not exsheets, is there any other pacakge that will do it? :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think a satisfactory solution can be obtained with `exsheets` but it can with its successor [`xsim`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xsim) – the trick is to define another exercise type solely used for the subquestions.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xsim}

\DeclareExerciseType{subquestion}{
  exercise-env = question ,
  solution-env = answer ,
  exercise-name = Question ,
  solution-name = Answer ,
  exercise-template = item ,
  solution-template = item
}

\DeclareExerciseProperty{title}

\DeclareExerciseEnvironmentTemplate{named}
  {\subsection*{\GetExercisePropertyTF{title}{#1}{??}}}
  {}

\DeclareExerciseEnvironmentTemplate{item}
  {\item}
  {}

\xsimsetup{
  exercise/template = named
}

\DeclareExerciseCollection{exercise-pool}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-exercises.tex}
\begin{question}
  Who is the Defence Minister?
\end{question}
\begin{question}
  Who is the Home Minister?
\end{question}
\begin{question}
  Who is the Finance Minister?
\end{question}
\begin{question}
  Who is the External Affairs Minister?
\end{question}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\collectexercises{exercise-pool}
\input{\jobname-exercises.tex}
\collectexercisesstop{exercise-pool}

\begin{exercise}[title=Answer the following in one sentence:]
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item Who is the President?
    \item Who is the Prime Minister?
    \printrandomexercises[collection=exercise-pool]{2}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{exercise}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

PS: the code requires `xsim` v0.10 which at the time of writing (2017-09-18 14:57 CEST) is not yet available but is on its way to CTAN (and the popular distributions).

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for. But my xsim is not v0.10 so I am unable to confirm. I will keep an eye for xsim 0.10.

Comment: @deshmukh I sent the version to CTAN, the update should be available in a few days

Comment: I updated xsim to remote rev 45355 (0.10) and tried compiling the code. It fails. The log file shows: ! Undefined control sequence.
l.211 \file_input_stop:
                       
? 
! Emergency stop.
l.211 \file_input_stop:

Does xsim need some other package that I might be missing?

Comment: @deshmukh *never* update a package alone. *Always* update your complete TeX distribution using the according package manager. You are missing updated versions of packages on which `xsim` relies upon!

Comment: Sorry, it took me so long to get back. I reinstalled TexLive2017 and compiled the file. But it does not show random questions. It shows only the first two questions. It showed an error that random numbers were not available so I installed `lcg` package. And recompiled. But still no luck. It still shows the static questions. Am I missing a package? Is there a way to share the logfile with you? It is too long to be copy-pasted here.

Comment: @deshmukh did you update the distribution with tlmgr?

Comment: No. I did not. I installed TexLive 2017. I did not install 'full'. Full is about 5Gb download and on slow internet connections could take forever. Instead, I installed only basic things and then added packages as I encountered errors. It is showing an error of 'Random numbers unavailable'. May be, I need to install the package that provides the random numbers for selecting the questions?

Comment: @deshmukh you need to have the *complete* l3kernel installed and its probably best also to have the l3packages installed

Comment: I have both the packages - l3kernel and l3packages installed. But it still shows the same error. Do you mean something more than just l3kernel package when you say _complete_ l3kernel?

Comment: @deshmukh Then I can't guess what the problem is. I am sure it is due to an incomplete installation but...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66583/discussion-between-deshmukh-and-clemens).

Comment: Finally, I found out what was going wrong. I was compiling using xelatex and it would then fail. One has to compile using pdflatex and compile it twice to get the desired output. Please correct me if this is wrong.

Comment: @deshmukh interesting. Yes, you're right. I wasn't aware that random numbers are engine dependent

Comment: @deshmukh I will add something to the manual

Comment: It would be great if you could make it compile correctly with xelatex also. That will enable setting up quizzes, worksheets in other languages, too.

Comment: @deshmukh that's not in my hands. The underlying function is part of the [l3kernel](https://ctan.org/pkg/l3kernel) and developed by the LaTeX team