# How to do subexercises or exercise parts with the xsim package?

Tags: exam, exercises, xsim

I quite often see, and myself create, exercises which consist of multiple subexercises or parts, like this:

```
# Exercise 1
Two cars are traveling in opposite directions. 
They are 2.7km apart, driving 50km/h and 65km/h, respectively.
a) Write the equations of motion for the two cars.
b) Find the time t at which the two cars will meet.
c) Find the distance traveled by the cars when they meet.
```

As far as I can see, this is not a feature directly provided by the xsim package. Any recommendations on how to achieve this by other means?

A solution with the enumerate or itemize environment works, but maybe there are other ways.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xsim}
\begin{document}
\begin{exercise}
Two cars travel ....
\begin{enumerate}
\item Write the equations ...
\item Find the time ...
\item Find the distance ...
\end{enumerate}
\end{exercise}
\end{document}
```

If one uses a solution like the above one, one has to keep the subexercises or parts in the same order in both the exercise and solution environment manually.

Comment: Which features of an xsim exercise do you need for your subexercises?

Comment: For my purpose it is mostly the automatic numbering and keeping exercises/solutions paired up correctly. If I change the order of my enumerate items in the `exercise` environment, then I manually have to change them in the in the `solution` environment as well. Some people might want some points bookkeeping to work with subexercises/parts as well.

Comment: This is trivial in the Exercise package.

Comment: At this moment I do not recall why I was displeased with the [Exercise package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/exercise). Maybe it didn't internationalize well, did not work well with xelatex, with the Tufte book classes or some such. Anyway, the xsim package appear like a fine package, and this is an obvious question about it (or request for improvement).

Comment: @clemens (the developer of xsim) Any idea on how to proceed?

Answer (score 2):

I'd simply use `enumerate` or `tasks` (from the `tasks` package).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xsim,tasks,siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{exercise}[subtitle=Cars]
  Two cars are traveling in opposite directions. They are
  \SI{2.7}{\kilo\meter} apart, driving \SI{50}{\kilo\meter\per\hour} and
  \SI{65}{\kilo\meter\per\hour}, respectively.
  \begin{tasks}(2)
    \task Write the equations of motion for the two cars. (\addpoints{1})
    \task Find the time $t$ at which the two cars will meet. (\addpoints{2})
    \task Find the distance traveled by the cars when they
      meet. (\addpoints{2})
  \end{tasks}
\end{exercise}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Depending on your setup it might also be a possibility to use `xsim`'s environments for the subexercises directly. An example for this can be found here: [Randomly selecting subquestions in exsheets](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/391530/).