XSim: Have a set of exercises with individual solution, but under a sole "Exercise n"
I wish to give students long series of exercises (imagine 3 x 15 calculations to do).
I want to keep each solution tied to each exercise, but using "exercise" and "solution" blocks each will lead to a heavy layout, with an "exercise" title for each calculation (45 then!).
How can I have what is considered as 1 "Exercise" (with a main title "Resolve the following calculations") but keep each calculus tied to its solution?
I've checked the following but I doubt it applies to my setup?
Custom enumeration of a list of exercises
My MWE is below (apologies, that wasn't clear enough). The issues with it are:

I'd like the first set of exercises to be numbered "1", the second set 2, and avoid numbers for each exercise.
I don't understand why the first exercise is numbered "1" and all other ones are titles "exercise" without a number.
I'd like the individual calulations not to be preceded by "exercise". It's too heavy.
When presenting solutions, even if I use a collection, I'd like solutions to be regrouped by section. "printsolutions" aloows to select a section, but to my knowledge, not to have exercises and solutions alternating.

Thank you!
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage{xsim,lipsum,xcolor}

\xsimsetup{
 solution/print = false
}

\DeclareExerciseCollection{deriv-easy}
\DeclareExerciseCollection{deriv-medium}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chap one}

\collectexercises{deriv-easy}
\begin{exercise}
$(x^2)'=$
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
$2x$
\end{solution}
\begin{exercise}
$(x^3)'=$
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
$3x^2$
\end{solution}
\begin{exercise}
$(x^4)'=$
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
$4x^3$
\end{solution}
\collectexercisesstop{deriv-easy}

\collectexercises{deriv-medium}
\begin{exercise}
$(7x^2)'=$
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
$14x$
\end{solution}
\begin{exercise}
$(5x^3)'=$
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
$15x^2$
\end{solution}
\begin{exercise}
$(2x^4)'=$
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
$8x^2$
\end{solution}
\collectexercisesstop{deriv-medium}

\section{Exercices easy}
\printcollection{deriv-easy}

\section{Exercices medium}
\printcollection{deriv-medium}

\section{Exercices and solutions}
\printcollection[headings=true,headings-template=per-section,print=both]{deriv-easy}
\printcollection[headings=true,headings-template=collection,print=both]{deriv-easy}

\end{document}

Text-wise, the layout I'd like is:
1.1 Exercises easy
Exercise 1: Resolve the following calculations
X^2'
X^3'
X^4'
1.2 Exercises medium
Exercise 1: Resolve the following calculations
7X^2'
5X^3'
2X^4'
1.3 Exercises and solutions
Solution to exercises from section 1.1
(each exercise and solution)
Solution to exercises from section 1.2
(each exercise and solution)

You can customize XSIM exercises to remove the title. You should provide a minimal working example (MWE) and an illustration of the expected result.

xsim allows you to create templates. Create your own to remove the heading. Something like
\DeclareExerciseEnvironmentTemplate{custom}
    {\IfInsideSolutionTF{~}{}}
    {\IfSolutionPrintTF{\IfInsideSolutionT{\par}}{\par}}

and set it with
\xsimsetup{
 exercise/template = custom,
 solution/template = custom,
}

You can also define collection headings. For example:
\DeclareExerciseHeadingTemplate{collection-exercise}
    {Exercise : Resolve the following calculations\label{\currentcollection}\par}

\DeclareExerciseHeadingTemplate{collection-solution}
    {Solution to exercises from section \ref{\currentcollection} (each exercise and solution)\par}

where \currentcollection is set to the collection name by redefining \printcollection
\newcommand*{\currentcollection}{}
\NewCommandCopy{\xsimprintcollection}{\printcollection}
\RenewDocumentCommand{\printcollection}{ O{} m }
    {%
      \renewcommand*{\currentcollection}{#2}
      \xsimprintcollection[#1]{#2}
    }

(as I understand, section is a property of an exercise, not a collection).
Full example:
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage{xsim,lipsum,xcolor}

\DeclareExerciseCollection{deriv-easy}
\DeclareExerciseCollection{deriv-medium}

\DeclareExerciseEnvironmentTemplate{custom}
    {\IfInsideSolutionTF{~}{}}
    {\IfSolutionPrintTF{\IfInsideSolutionT{\par}}{\par}}

\newcommand*{\currentcollection}{}
\NewCommandCopy{\xsimprintcollection}{\printcollection}
\RenewDocumentCommand{\printcollection}{ O{} m }
    {%
      \renewcommand*{\currentcollection}{#2}
      \xsimprintcollection[#1]{#2}
    }

\DeclareExerciseHeadingTemplate{collection-exercise}
    {Exercise : Resolve the following calculations\label{\currentcollection}\par}

\DeclareExerciseHeadingTemplate{collection-solution}
    {Solution to exercises from section \ref{\currentcollection} (each exercise and solution)\par}

\xsimsetup{
 exercise/template = custom,
 solution/template = custom,
 print-collection/headings = true,
 print-collection/headings-template = collection-exercise,
}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chap one}

\collectexercises{deriv-easy}
\begin{exercise}
$(x^2)'=$
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
$2x$
\end{solution}
\begin{exercise}
$(x^3)'=$
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
$3x^2$
\end{solution}
\begin{exercise}
$(x^4)'=$
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
$4x^3$
\end{solution}
\collectexercisesstop{deriv-easy}

\collectexercises{deriv-medium}
\begin{exercise}
$(7x^2)'=$
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
$14x$
\end{solution}
\begin{exercise}
$(5x^3)'=$
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
$15x^2$
\end{solution}
\begin{exercise}
$(2x^4)'=$
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
$8x^3$
\end{solution}
\collectexercisesstop{deriv-medium}

\section{Exercices easy}
\printcollection{deriv-easy}

\section{Exercices medium}
\printcollection{deriv-medium}

\section{Exercices and solutions}
\xsimsetup{
  solution/print=true, % needed for \IfSolutionPrintTF
  print-collection/headings-template = collection-solution,
  print-collection/print=both,
}

\printcollection{deriv-easy}

\bigskip

\printcollection{deriv-medium}

\end{document}



Thank you so much! I was drowning in the CTAN package doc and could not find my way... With this, I'm saved!
A last one: Could I, instead of hardcoding the title of exercises with "DeclareExerciseHeadingTemplate", have it as a parameter when I create an exercise?
For example, I'd use something like this, when I create a collection:
\collectexercises{deriv-easy}{"Perform the following calculation"}
And when I call "\printcollection{deriv-easy}"
It would print
Perform the following calculation
Followed by all exercises of that collection?

@Gauffke I never tried, but it seems that xsim exercises can be nested. You can define an exercise type for each question (each derivative) and another for each difficulty (each collection). See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/391968/316068.

Thank you for your help!
